# What are the most simple and suitable statistical analysis to use on SPSS for objectives;

Tags: testing, statistics, data-analysis, spss, statistical-test

What are the most simple and suitable statistical analysis to use on SPSS for objectives;

1. To investigate impact of COVID-19 on age, sex and gender where gender is nominal and age and sex are scales?
2. To examine the health implementation of COVID-19. All variables are scales.

3 To assess impact of policy regulations on education. All variables are scales.

I need the right statistics analysis plans for these objectives. The age and race have missing values. Thank you.